# Forbidden Exception on accessing AWS Iot using Amazon Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I am creating an android application which connects to AWS IoT using Amazon Cognito authentication. I am able to authenticate user successfully and I am able get the credentials.
While updating the thing shadow using these credentials always return 403 Forbidden Exception. I have tried all my ways to troubleshoot the issue but I found no solutions.

My IAM Policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:GetThingShadow",
                "iot:UpdateThingShadow",

            ],
            "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:iot:us-west-2:<my_account>:thing/mythingname"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Android code for connecting endpoint:

```
userSession= AppHelper.getCurrSession();
credentialsProvider=new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getApplicationContext(),POOL_ID,REGIONS);

    Map<String,String> logins=new HashMap<String, String>();
    logins.put("cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/user_pool_id",userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());

    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
    iotDataClient=new AWSIotDataClient(credentialsProvider);

    iotDataClient.setEndpoint(ENDPOINT);
```

Updating thing shadow:

```
 UpdateThingShadowRequest request=new UpdateThingShadowRequest();
            request.setThingName(thingName);

            ByteBuffer payloadBuffer=ByteBuffer.wrap(updateState.getBytes());
            request.setPayload(payloadBuffer);

            UpdateThingShadowResult result=iotDataClient.updateThingShadow(request);
```

Any help with this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: To what Cognito role is this IAM policy attached, Authenticated or Unauthenticated role? What authentication provider are you using, if any?

Comment: I am using Authenticated role.As a provider I am using identity pool integrated with user pool

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue as you. I've found a solution.

That 403 status code mean that you need authorization.

If you read this documentation (near the end) : [Publish/Subscribe Policy Exemple](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html) it's stated that you need **2 policies** to make it work with Authenticated Cognito User. One for the Cognito Identity Pool and another for the Cognito User.

It's not possible to attach a policy to a cognito user with the UI, but you can do it through the CLI.

The command to attach a policy to a cognito user is :

`aws iot attach-principal-policy --principal "cognito user id" --policy-Name "policy name"`

You can find your **cognito user id** in :

`Cognito > Manager Federated Identities > choose your identity pool > identity browser > and find your identity ID`

I use this policy for testing purpose.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
     ]
 }
```

To make it reusable, you need to use a lambda function (here in JavaScript).

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var iot = new AWS.Iot();

exports.handler = function(event, context, cb) {
    var params = {
        policyName: 'your policy',
        principal: 'your cognito id'
    };

    var out = iot.attachPrincipalPolicy(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) cb(err);
        else cb(null, data); 
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment, this was exactly what I needed to do! I have a question about the last step (putting it in a Lambda function.) Is there a trigger/event that you could use to automatically run the lambda?

Comment: @TurnerHoughton Thanks. It was a little bit hard to find this solution, I'm glad it helped you. For your question it depends on what you want to do, for me I created a path in api gateway called /register that will register an iot device to a specific user account.

Comment: Do you have some logic on the front end that determines when you hit that endpoint? Or do you just run it every time the user logs in? Because it only needs to be ran once per user, right?

Comment: My flow was, A user have an account, he logged in, then he register the device once, hence the device is now tied to the user account. It's not run every time the user logged in, you are right. If you have more questions, I can give you my mail.

Comment: Attaching a policy it's inteded for other AWS IoT resources like device certificates or something like that (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_AttachPolicy.html). I'm attaching a policy to my cognito user using the indentity id and AttachPolicy is working, but the whole access to the IoT resource (like publish) depends 100% of my IAM role policies... Please tell ASAP me if I'm missing here

Comment: @JoséPulido I think it's better to create a new issue, so I can help

Answer (score 0):

I am able to identify the issue. In my case, I was missing to set `region` for `AWS iot` client.

```
Region region = Region.getRegion(MY_REGION);
mIotAndroidClient.setRegion(region); // I was missing this piece of code
```