# Amazon AWS IOT device SDK provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-sdk, beagleboneblack, provisioning

I am new to AWS IOT. I'm working on a project where I use BeagleBone boards as device gateways which will connect to AWS IoT. I wish to use either the C or C++ device SDKs on the boards to communicate with AWS IoT.

The problem I have is with the provisioning and authentication phase. It is easy to create a "thing" via AWS IoT cloud, generate keys, X.509 certificates for the device and then copy them to the device.

However, it would be ideal to generate the keys and certificate on the device itself during provisioning (this is possible of course), but then automatically communicate with AWS IoT via the SDKs and assign the X.509 certificate to a "thing" already registered there.

Is there any API for doing this? I feel there is a lack of application examples out there. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Maybe the response here is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202668/creating-aws-iot-things-with-policies-and-certificates-on-the-fly/48890225#48890225